# why can't extern find the parameter defined in dll?

Tags: c++

In dll there is a parameter `GlobalVariable_M` defined in a cpp file.

**DLLVariableDefined.cpp** of dll source code

```
...
std::int GlobalVariable_M; // defined a variable here
...
```

In my program, I want my program to find this variable.

**MyProgram.cpp** of program that links to the dll

```
#include <DLLVariableDefined.h>
...
extern std::int GlobalVariable_M
...
```

Comment: `std::int`? That's not proper C++.

Comment: What error message are you encountering?

Comment: And how to solve your problem, you need to learn how to *export* and *import* declarations and symbols on your system.